Windows obtener fecha del sistema del día anterior
En Windows ¿ Como puedo obtener la fecha del sistema del día anterior desde la línea de comandos ?
Por ejemplo la actual seria:
echo %date%

¿ Pero como le puedo restar un día a la que me da el sistema ?

En CMD directamente no puedes sin ser un archivo por lote, pero como mencionas la palabra script tiene dos vias o lo haces directamente con PowerShell a traves de un archivo agregando estos comando:
$FechaAnterior = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Write-Host $FechaAnterior

Guardalo con el nombre que quieras por ejemplo obtener_fecha_anterior.ps1
y lo ejecutas asi:
powershell obtener_fecha_anterior.ps1

...o puedes hacer un archivo .bat desde el bloc de notas y le agregas lo siguiente:
@echo off
REM Obtiene la fecha actual
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set datetime=%%I
REM Extrae el año, mes y día
set year=%datetime:~0,4%
set month=%datetime:~4,2%
set day=%datetime:~6,2%
REM Resta un día
set /a day=day-1
REM Ajusta el día si es necesario (por ejemplo, si el día es 0)
if %day% equ 0 (
    set /a month=month-1
    if %month% equ 0 (
        set /a year=year-1
        set month=12
    )
    set /a day=31
    REM Verificar si el año es bisiesto y ajustar febrero si es necesario
    if %month% equ 2 (
        if %year% equ 1900 set /a leap=1
        if %year% lss 1900 set /a leap=0
        if %year% geq 1900 set /a "leap=(year %% 4)==0 && (year %% 100)!=0 || (year %% 400)==0"
        if %leap% equ 1 set /a day=29
    )
)
REM Formatea la fecha
if %month% lss 10 set month=0%month%
if %day% lss 10 set day=0%day%
set FechaAnterior=%year%%month%%day%
echo %FechaAnterior%


El echo final te dará la fecha.
Guardas el archivo con el nombre que quieras, abres CMD y lo ajecutas
obtener_fecha_anterior.bat

IMPORTANTE en ambos para ejecutarlo debes estar posicionado en el directorio donde lo guardastes.

Excelente aportacion ! Gracias

Si desde el cmd pongo powershell obtener_fecha_anterior.ps1 me sale un mensaje de error "obtener_fecha_anterior.ps1: El término 'obtener_fecha_anterior.ps1' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo script o programa ejecutable."

Y en el otro ejemplo de obtener fecha desde .bat no se tiene en cuenta los meses de febrero o si es bisiesto?

@Popularfan Listo ya edite la respuesta, aqui toma en cuenta el Bisiestro

@Popularfan En cuanto al mensaje de error del PowerShell fue lo que te comente en la respuesta, asegúrate de estar parado en el directorio donde esta el script y ejecutalo allí.

pues sigue dandome el mismo error si quiero usar powershell y estoy en el mismo directorio donde esta el script. ¿ No habra que añadir algun parametro mas a powershell ?

@Popularfan Pudiera ser un problema de permiso de ejecucion o que tengas deshabilitado las extenciones ".ps1"

Ok lo mirare ! Gracias por tu ayuda
